# Fragment Transitions: shared elements

Tags: java, android, animation, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

easiest way to show you what I'm trying to achive is this video:

[shared image in fragment transition](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/assets/videos/posts/2014/12/04/news-opt.mp4)

I have one activity and two fragments (FragA and FragB). Is there a way to do this kind of transitions on Android 5 without changing activity?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be something that you are looking for: https://bitbucket.org/brockoli/fragmentsharedelements/src/87421a65f2aaf5f99b0e48acbf4b31551e9118fc/app/src/main/java/com/brockoli/android/fragmentsharedelements/MyActivity.java?at=master